# In C# Object Instantiation, is a Null Check Needed if Catching Exceptions

Tags: c#, null, instantiation

I have been looking on stackoverflow, but do not see the ansswer yet. Note: that I did see some good responses in C++, but not C#.

Is there any benefit in checking for null `if (reader == null)` as below, or will issues causing it to be null already cause an exception making `if (reader == null)` unreachable (with reader == null being true)?

```
try
{
    var reader = new PhotoReader();
    if (reader == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("PhotoReader could not be created.");
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // let user know failed object creation, etc.
    <...>
}
```

Comment: CodeCaster regarding duplicate: That is great. I just did not see it from my search criteria. Please point me to the duplicate and I will check it out. Thank you.

Comment: CodeCaster: Just let me know if I should delete this even though it has answers. Difference in title may cause this to come up in searches versus the other. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no way you get `null` as result of contructor call in c#.

Constructor may throw an exception itself, but it will break your execution flow anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you instantiate `reader` by assigning the result of a class's constructor means that it will never be null, so that check is unnecessary.